# Clicking Back button in Chrome affects my Vue app in cross-origin iframe instead of original page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, vue-router, html5-history

So basically I'm building an Chrome Extension, and I append an iframe with my Vue app to mail.google.com page, and I do all of the routing inside my Vue app with `vue-router`.

Strange thing is, when I click the Back button in my browser (Chrome), it takes my Vue app in iframe one page back instead of doing that with parent page (`mail.google.com`).

How can I make it that clicking browser’s back button affect only parent page (`mail.google.com`) and not my Vue app in appended iframe?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  It appears I have a similar problem with the browser history being affected by iframes in chrome extensions.

Comment: @DaveKearney IIRC I had some success with changing `mode` parameter of router instance to `history` instead of default `hash`, but I have no access to that repo anymore so I can't confirm unfortunately..

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @kecman.  Looks like I may have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that loading an iframe with an address causes the history to update.  Early testing says that something like this seems to work:

```
        <Iframe
            url={"#"}
            width="0px"
            height="0px"
            frameBorder="0"
            id="my-iframe"
            display="initial"
            position="absolute"
            style={{border: "none", display: "none", position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0}}
            onLoad={() => {
                const el = document.getElementById('my-iframe')
                if (!loaded) {
                    const svrHost = "https://my-host.com/iframe.html"
                    el.contentWindow.location.replace(svrHost);
                    setLoaded(true);
                }
            }}
        />
```

I would love to tell you where I found this, but I located hints on a number of websites and don't remember the sources.

Comment: One of the source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/prevent-back-button-to-work-on-iframe-instead-of-the-parent/15380/2